# Historical data using Reddit API

Tags: python, api, data-science, reddit, praw

I am trying to access historical data of mentions of a few keywords for a data analysis project using Reddit API. Utilizing python's wonderful easy-to-use PRAW package to fetch the data. Does anyone know if Reddit api has any functionality that allows historical access to data from a subreddit?

Comment: What do you mean by historical? Have you looked at [`submissions`](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submissions)? Without any `start` and `end` parameters, that will fetch literally every single post made to a subreddit (while following Reddit's API rules, so it might take some time).

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the last 1000 items for a specific view. Use the `Subreddit`'s [`submissions`](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submissions) property.

You can get the different views. I describe some of the other views in [a reddit comment I made](https://old.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/9vmpqt/hello_is_there_a_limit_to_how_far_back_in_a_subs/e9deohf/):

> yes. generally speaking you can get the last 1000 items in a listing
>   (/r/all and /r/popular listings are higher), regardless of how long
>   ago it is.
>
> to get more than 1000 items:
>
> - check all of the views (/r/subreddit/top, etc) and over all of the time scales
>
> check all of the moderation queues (with parameter `only=links`):
>
> - unmoderated (/about/unmoderated)
> - moderation queue (/about/modqueue)
> - spam (/about/spam)
> - edited (/about/edited)
> - reports (/about/reports)
>
> if this is a public subreddit, consider also using pushshift.io